# How to make a class in Swift extend a concrete class and conform to multiple protocols?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift-extensions, swift4.2

## Background

I am creating an extension for `UITableViewController` like so:

```
func attachToController<C: UIViewController>(_ sender: C, alignTo: UIView, to: ALEdge = .top , withOffset: CGFloat = 0.0)
    where C: UITableViewDataSource, C:UITableViewDelegate
{
    self.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    ..
    self.delegate = sender as UITableViewDelegate
    self.dataSource = sender as UITableViewDataSource
}
```

Currently the class that's using this extension is declared like so:

```
final class MyViewController: UIViewController {
```

then I call this in view did load:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setupTableView()
}

..

func setupTableView() {
    self.tableView.attachToController(self, alignTo: self.view, withOffset: 0.0)
    ..
 }
```

But I'm getting the error

> Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView'

I would like to declare `MyViewController` so that it extends `UIViewController` and also conforms to the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols.. ideas?

Note: I'm using Swift 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it

```
final class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
```

Also if the `attachToController(...)` extension is on `UITableViewController` it won't work, I assume according to how you call it, you want it to be on `UITableView`

Comment: it works just fine.. i'm doing this `self.tableView.attachToController`